# CSS is not working on my GitHub "website"

Tags: css, file

Hello guys i've tried several method to put the website i have created online with GitHub, I finally succeed to put CSS and JS files with my index.html but it only display my HTML, my "index.html" file, without any CSS.
It's strange since I've put my CSS files on GitHub?

here is my repository : 
https://github.com/Ziratsu/Ziratsu.github.io

Thank's if you take time to give me a hand, this is my first real project for a customer, and even if it's not totally finished I want to give him a look.
(Sorry for the english)

Comment: Looks like the `css` folder isn't published.

Comment: it's the "style.css" in the CSS folder.

Comment: I know. But it didn't get published for whatever reason. It gives a 404 Not Found error.

Comment: I think i've write CSS instead of css

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be [similar to this case](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/i-pushed-my-website-to-github-pages-and-now-my-css-styles-no-longer-work), where the source code included:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"  type="text/css"/>
```

But:

> Your [CSS folder is in all uppercase](https://github.com/ehewett/BBC). Your files link to css in lower case. File paths are case sensitive.